# Apache is caching all the responses

Tags: php, apache, caching

I have a peculiar problem:
2 systems apparently identical:

- MacOS with APACHE2 + PHP5.5 and /var/www/html with static html and a css
- Docker Container with same stuff. Both are mapping same /var/www/html
- If I am modifying the MACOS server files, any browser refresh will    see the changes
- If I am modifying the docker files, I cannot see the changes until I restart the whole docker.

**Experiments:**

- used CURL inside docker machine: result -> cached response (wanted to eliminate browser caching)
- added html, css and js files to php handler (SetHandler application/x-httpd-php): result -> WORKED!!!! but not happy since php should care about .php files only

**Both servers have same httpd modules**
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 unixd_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)

**Any thoughts?**

Comment: Apparently is not all apache 100%. Is a docker issue on mac host. 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18246

Comment: For the moment I am bypassing this issue by forcing static files through php (not ideal): <filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>